# NexGen Gallery Wordpress HTTPS Update

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, nextgen-gallery

I am wanting to serve me website via HTTPS only. This means updating all inks to HTTPS. I am unable to update all links that are using the NextGen Gallery Plugin.

Does anyone know the fix to update all links using this plugin?

I have already tried updating the standard Wordpress URL via the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. It turns out you have to clear the cache in the NextGen Gallery.

Go to Dashboard > Gallery > Other Options > Miscellaneous and click the button "clear image cache".

I then cleared out my W3 Total Cache -- just in case -- and made sure my CDN was on development. When I checked it, https: worked and the Gallery images were served securely.